# DER Aluno Pergunta Tema

Tags: relacionamento, diagrama

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de controle de aprendizado, onde terei um banco de perguntas que serão listadas em uma atividade e posteriormente respondidas pelos alunos. Assim que o aluno responder a pergunta, gostaria de armazenar se ele acertou ou errou a questão.

O ponto chave do meu sistema é permitir um acompanhamento do aprendizado do aluno, então pensei em armazenar no banco o número de questões que ele errou e acertou de cada tema. Meu problema é como demonstrar isso no DER.

Segue abaixo o meu DER atual.

[image: DER APRENDIZADO]

Answer (score 4):

No seu lugar, colocaria a resposta na associação `Pergunta_Atividade`:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                 Pergunta_Atividade                 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| IdPerguntaAtividade integer primary key            |
| IdPergunta integer foreign key (Pergunta)          |
| IdAtividade integer foreign key (Atividade)        |
| Resposta integer not null                          |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

O cálculo das respostas corretas seria um `INNER JOIN` entre `Pergunta_Atividade`, `Atividade` e `Pergunta`, feito na aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Para facilitar suas operações, você pode criar uma tabela de histórico

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                 HistoricoPerguntas                 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| IdHistoricoPerguntas integer primary key           |
| IdPergunta integer foreign key (Pergunta)          | 
| IdAluno integer                                    |
| IdAtividade integer foreign key (Atividade)        |
| Resposta integer not null                          |
| Correta integer                                    |
| DataResposta date                                  |
| ...                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

E com mais informações que você julgar necessário.
Assim você tem uma tabela que contém o histórico das perguntas e respostas, a data, a assertividade, e mais o que você julgar necessário.

Answer (score 0):

Na entidade **Aluno_Atividade**, você pode incluir um campo com a resposta e até se está correta ou não, talvez um campo para algum tipo de observação.

E com base nesse relacionamento você vai conseguir extrair o detalhe que quiser para um relatório final.