# Questionário Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou criando um sistema de avaliações, onde os professores irão alimentar um banco de perguntas que posteriormente farão parte de atividades que serão disponibilizadas para os alunos.

Minha dúvida é na hora de apresentar a atividade para os alunos, onde preciso listar todas as perguntas e suas alternativas e depois armazenar as respostas dos alunos.

Segue abaixo o DER do problema:
[image: Der]

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "onde"?

Comment: O "onde" ficou mal expressado. Pensei em criar uma view que liste todas as perguntas e traga combobox para as alternativas. Minha dúvida é como salvar todas as respostas quando o aluno clicar em finalizar

Comment: Poste o que você já fez. Precisamos ver onde está para ajudar.

Comment: No momento eu já cadastro as perguntas, atividades, professores e alunos. Estou terminando de subir as ultimas modificações no git, e já mando o link do repositorio

Comment: Melhor você ler isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://github.com/viniciusjlima/sistemaAvaliacoes.git

Comment: Ok. Irei melhorar minha pergunta

Comment: Tenho a impressão de que já respondi isso. [Não seria isto aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82103/der-aluno-pergunta-tema)?